# Detrending a time-series of a multi-dimensional array without the for loops

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, scipy

I have a 3D array which has a time-series of air-sea carbon flux for each grid point on the earth's surface (model output). I want to remove the trend (linear) in the time series. I came across this code:

```
from matplotlib import mlab

for x in xrange(40):
    for y in xrange(182):
        cflux_detrended[:, x, y] = mlab.detrend_linear(cflux[:, x, y])
```

Can I speed this up by not using for loops?

Comment: Do you really want to remove separate trends at each gridpoint as in the double loop, or do you want to remove a common trend? Both can be done as one big linear model fit and predict, with stacking or reshaping.

Comment: @user333700 I guess I would like to have a look at both results. I see that removing the trend of the data would be more useful than removing the trend at each gridpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions using numpy.linalg.lstsq. This version uses np.vander to create any polynomial trend.

Warning: not tested except on the example.

I think something like this will be added to scikits.statsmodels, which doesn't have yet a multivariate version for detrending either. For the common trend case, we could use scikits.statsmodels OLS and we would also get all the result statistics for the estimation.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Detrending multivariate array

Created on Fri Dec 02 15:08:42 2011

Author: Josef Perktold

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355197/detrending-a-time-series-of-a-multi-dimensional-array-without-the-for-loops

I should also add the multivariate version to statsmodels

"""

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def detrend_common(y, order=1):
    '''detrend multivariate series by common trend

    Paramters
    ---------
    y : ndarray
       data, can be 1d or nd. if ndim is greater then 1, then observations
       are along zero axis
    order : int
       degree of polynomial trend, 1 is linear, 0 is constant

    Returns
    -------
    y_detrended : ndarray
       detrended data in same shape as original 

    '''
    nobs = y.shape[0]
    shape = y.shape
    y_ = y.ravel()
    nobs_ = len(y_)
    t = np.repeat(np.arange(nobs), nobs_ /float(nobs))
    exog = np.vander(t, order+1)
    params = np.linalg.lstsq(exog, y_)[0]
    fittedvalues = np.dot(exog, params)
    resid = (y_ - fittedvalues).reshape(*shape)
    return resid, params

def detrend_separate(y, order=1):
    '''detrend multivariate series by series specific trends

    Paramters
    ---------
    y : ndarray
       data, can be 1d or nd. if ndim is greater then 1, then observations
       are along zero axis
    order : int
       degree of polynomial trend, 1 is linear, 0 is constant

    Returns
    -------
    y_detrended : ndarray
       detrended data in same shape as original 

    '''
    nobs = y.shape[0]
    shape = y.shape
    y_ = y.reshape(nobs, -1)
    kvars_ = len(y_)
    t = np.arange(nobs)
    exog = np.vander(t, order+1)
    params = np.linalg.lstsq(exog, y_)[0]
    fittedvalues = np.dot(exog, params)
    resid = (y_ - fittedvalues).reshape(*shape)
    return resid, params

nobs = 30
sige = 0.1
y0 = 0.5 * np.random.randn(nobs,4,3)
t = np.arange(nobs)
y_observed = y0 + t[:,None,None]

for detrend_func, name in zip([detrend_common, detrend_separate], 
                               ['common', 'separate']):
    y_detrended, params = detrend_func(y_observed, order=1)
    print '\n\n', name 
    print 'params for detrending'
    print params
    print 'std of detrended', y_detrended.std()  #should be roughly sig=0.5 (var of y0)
    print 'maxabs', np.max(np.abs(y_detrended - y0))

    print 'observed'
    print y_observed[-1]
    print 'detrended'
    print y_detrended[-1]
    print 'original "true"'
    print y0[-1]

    plt.figure()
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(3):
            plt.plot(y0[:,i,j], 'bo', alpha=0.75)
            plt.plot(y_detrended[:,i,j], 'ro', alpha=0.75)
    plt.title(name + ' detrending: blue - original, red - detrended')


plt.show()
```

Since Nicholas pointed out scipy.signal.detrend. My detrend separate is basically the same as scipy.signal.detrend with fewer (no axis or breaks) or different (with polynomial order) options.

```
>>> res = signal.detrend(y_observed, axis=0)
>>> (res - y0).var()
0.016931858083279336
>>> (y_detrended - y0).var()
0.01693185808327945
>>> (res - y_detrended).var()
8.402584948582852e-30
```

Comment: @Thanks for your time. I have tried it and using detrend_seperate returns the same result as the original post and scipy.signal.detrend. I have tried using detrend_common but I have a masked array so I filled the masked values with zeros and it worked great. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 4):

Scipy has a lot of [signal processing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) tools. 
Using `scipy.signal.detrend()` will remove the linear trend along an axis of the data. From the documentation it looks like the linear trend of the complete data set will be subtracted from the time-series at each grid point.

```
import scipy.signal
cflux_detrended = scipy.signal.detrend(cflux, axis=0)
```

Using `scipy.signal` will get the same result as using the method in the original post. Using Josef's `detrend_separate()` function will also return the same result.

[image: detrending cflux]

Comment: good to know. I didn't know or remember this one. I looked at the source and it looks similar to my separate trend version, restricted to linear trend (or constant), but more general otherwise. However, my numbers don't match up with signal.detrend. ???

Comment: @user333700 The answers match up very well.

Comment: @nicholaschris - does scipy enable you to detrend two dimensional data ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a plain old list comprehension is easiest:

```
cflux_detrended = np.array([[mlab.detrend_linear(t) for t in kk] for kk in cflux.T])
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to remember about list comprehensions.

Comment: When I try this piece of code as is, the result is very different from using the method in the question. Any reasons why this would be?